# C# WPF Grid Rows height stretch

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, height, row

I am trying to create a WPF view which grows dynamically with its window size. 
My example Code shows three.

The first one shall be with a fixed height.

The second and third one shall be the same size and always will the whole window.

Unfortunatelly it does not work. What am i doing wrong? Is the DockPanel the correct Tool for my purpose?

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <!-- Labels and Buttons -->
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView Margin="5"/>
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2">
        <ListView Margin="5"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">`?

Comment: I think another grid is the correct tool for your purpose

Comment: What means it is not working?

Comment: make the second and third listViews in the same dockpanel. Just insert inside dockpanel gird and make two grid columns(one for each listView). Then they should be with the same size

Comment: And the second and third controls would not be full window size, because you have 3 rows. In your desing buttons and labels will be on top, then will be second control (in the middle) with half of the space that left, and on bottom will be third listView

Comment: @Sasha Why should you do this? First of all Julian need rows and not columns and rows will have the same size when you set `Height=*` to the rows you want to have the same height. That's why I'm asking what's not working.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom May be I didn't understand a question... As I understood he wants controls to be full window size

Comment: @Sasha Yes, that's why I understand as well and with the xaml he provided will already fill the whole window. That's why I asked what's not working. And he don't need columns when he want's to have all three parts vertical ;)

Comment: Thanks fore all your replys. Basically nothing of it works. The listviews are empty at the program start. all three rows are put among each other with only the headlines shown

Comment: @JulianHerbel Because you need to bind data in Listviews : ItemsSource={Binding YourCollection}

Comment: oh man.. i am dumb. There was a stackpanel that was hiding in my xaml and it destroyed my view. The code as shown above is working perfectly. sorry for stealing your time and many thanks for pushing me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this information would not be possible to put in a comment.

Your layout still does what you want it to do.
I set some background colors to show it. For me this is an easy trick to check if my layout expands like I want it to.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="0"
               Background="Yellow">
        <!-- Labels and Buttons -->
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="1"
               Background="Aqua">
        <ListView Margin="5"
                  Background="Gray" />
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel Grid.Row="2"
               Background="Beige">
        <ListView Margin="5"
                  Background="Bisque" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image: Example]

If you don't see any data in your `ListView` it's not because of the layout. You have to check your bindings.

**Hint**

I would recommend using a `Border` or `Grid` instead of a `DockPanel` in your case because you don't need the features a `DockPanel` provides.